# In rust, I want to use slice.windows(2) and use x[0], x[1], What method should I choose?

Tags: rust, iterator, slice

```
pub fn train(&mut self, sequence: &[T]) -> &mut Chain<T> {
    println!("4444444444444444");
    let _ = sequence.windows(2).scan(1, |_state, x| {
        if !self.map.contains_key(&x[0]) {
            let mut map: HashMap<T, i32> = HashMap::new();
            map.entry(x[1]).or_insert(1);
            self.map.insert(x[0], map);
        }
        println!("22222222");
        Some(x)
    });
    println!("33333333333333333");
    self

}
```

The code between 4444 and 3333 does not run. I want to do the "if block", do I need to use method other than scan? I prefer not to use loop or for_each.

self is
`struct C<T>  where T:Eq+Hash+Clone+Copy, { map: HashMap<T, HashMap<T, i32>>  }`

Comment: *"I prefer not to use loop or for_each"* reads to me like "I want a solution but I don't want to use any of the recommended solutions and instead want to make my life as difficult as possible". What's the point?

Comment: It does look like a `for`-loop or `.for_each` will achieve your goals idiomatically. Why are they excluded?

Comment: If this is a challenge, I'd vote to close this question, because it will only confuse people that search for some actual guidance. You can't ask a question without preemptively excluding the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [chapter about iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) in the Rust book.

The important takeaway from the chapter is that iterators are lazy and need to be consumed to do anything. As you throw away the result before consuming it, nothing happens. `scan()` just creates a new iterator that also waits to be consumed.

Consuming methods include, for example, `for_each`, `collect`, `find`, `count` and similar. Basically all methods of `Iterator` that do not return a new iterator. Those functions will actually evaluate the iterator chain.

Note that some of the methods can decide to stop consuming the chain and discard the rest after they collected the information they gathered. For example, `all` will stop the iteration once it finds a `false`. Or `find` will stop the iteration once it found the element it was searching for. This is a behaviour called *short-circuiting*.

Finally, you could of course also manually query items from it with `next`.

If you just want an iterator to run (for debugging purposes), I recommend simply calling `count()`. It works with all types, evaluates to completion, can't fail, doesn't allocate additional memory and doesn't return a value that requires consumption.